# Setting a bitmap as the icon for a file in code

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a custom icon, which I have as a Bitmap, for a file in C#. I've followed the examples and suggestions provided in various sources, but I'm encountering an issue with the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify the file path
        string filePath = @"C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt";

        // Create a Bitmap representing your custom icon
        Bitmap customIconBitmap = new Bitmap("YourCustomIcon.bmp"); // Replace with your actual bitmap file

        // Convert the custom icon to an Icon
        Icon customIcon;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            customIconBitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); // Use the appropriate format for your icon
            customIcon = new Icon(stream);
        }

        // Verify that the file exists
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        // Get the handle to the in-memory icon
        IntPtr iconHandle = customIcon.Handle;

        // Open the file with write access to modify its icon
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            // Set the new icon to the file
            SetFileIcon(fileStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), iconHandle);
        }

        // Notify the system about the changes
        SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        Console.WriteLine("File icon changed successfully!");
    }

    // Declare the SHChangeNotify function from the Shell32.dll
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    public static extern void SHChangeNotify(long wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);

    // Declare the SetFileIcon function from the Shell32.dll
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetFileIcon(IntPtr hFile, IntPtr hIcon);
}
```

Details:

I have a custom icon represented as a Bitmap in my C# code.
I've tried converting the Bitmap to an Icon using a MemoryStream, but it's resulting in the mentioned ArgumentException.
The file I'm trying to associate the icon with does exist.
I've checked the image format used for the custom icon (ImageFormat.Png in my case).
Request for Help:

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to correctly set a Bitmap as the icon for a file in C#. If there are alternative approaches or corrections to my code, please share them. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get the idea that an API function named "SetFileIcon" exists? There is no information about such a function anywhere in the internet.

Comment: @NineBerry I got this code from ChatGPT and now it's not working and i don't know what to do.

Comment: Well, lesson to learn: ChatGPT is a notorious liar who often just invents things that don't exist in reality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Associate File Type and Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903702/associate-file-type-and-icon)

Comment: What *mentioned ArgumentException*? There's nothing about an exception except the one mention I quoted.

Comment: @NineBerry No .

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no way to set the icon that is shown for an individual file in Windows.

Exceptions:

- You can set the icon shown for a **link to a file (*.lnk)**, not the actual file itself. See [How do you create an application shortcut (.lnk file) in C# with command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501608/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-sharp-with-command-li)
- You can set the icon shown for a **link to a url (*.url)**. See [How to create an internet shortcut with an icon in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905879/how-to-create-an-internet-shortcut-with-an-icon-in-c)
- You can set the icon shown for a **folder**. See [C# How to set folder icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531898/c-sharp-how-to-set-folder-icon)
- You can (though not a good idea) replace the icon in an ***.exe file**. See [Programmatically change the icon of the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539095/programmatically-change-the-icon-of-the-executable)

Comment: Then how the other apps do this?

Comment: You will not find an app that can change the icon shown for one specific file. You can change the icon shown for all files with the same file extension. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that is very good too! Can you tell me how?

Comment: Ummmm... . I forgot something. If you saying that apps can't change a file icon then how the "resource hacker" do this?

Comment: For exectuable files (*.exe), Windows will show an icon present in the executable itself. Resource Hacker can exchange the icon in the exe file. That will only work for *.exe files, not for any other type of file.